# Retrieve the tables from SQL Server from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working with C# Visual studio and SQL Server as its backend. This is my code - I am trying to retrieve table names based on database name. The command which used that is working perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio query builder but when I am running this it showing error

> Object reference not set to instance of an object

on the following line

```
cmbAlterAdd1.Items.Add(Reader2["name"].ToString());
```

I given name because in result column name is coming has name only has shown image. I think I need expert advice to solve this problem please help!!

```
ConnectionPath = sqlPath;
DBName = databaseName;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionPath);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE "+DBName+" SELECT name FROM sys.Tables", con);
SqlDataReader Reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (Reader2.Read())
{
    cmbAlterAdd1.Items.Add(Reader2["name"].ToString());
}

con.Close();
```

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJC7D.jpg)

Comment: You should remove the "`USE ` + DBName " - you *already* define what database you want to work against in your *connection string*

Comment: Thanks for your quack comment marc_s your suggestion is right I updated my query but still error is not gone.

Comment: @marc_s That kind of depends, there are plenty of reasons why you might want to enumerate the tables from a secondary database.

Comment: I don't think that reader["name"] is null. Check your combobox please. Please tell us, which is null?

Comment: What is clear is the error does not come from the SQL query itself. It is a managed exception, meaning you are trying to read a null variable. What line does the error appear on? In Visual Studio, press Alt-Ctrl-E, and make sure the "Break" column is checked for managed exceptions.

Comment: @Berkay Yaylaci I tried with giving break point combobox showing null only

Comment: Another improvement might be to take advantage of the fact that SqlConnection and SqlCommand and SqlDataReader all implement IDisposable, and put them in using () { }; blocks...

Comment: @Santigo Where are you calling your code from? Is it possible you are trying to use a combo box before it has been added to the form?

Comment: @Santigo Where do you create your combobox? If really "cmbAlterAdd1" is null, then please update your question.

Comment: I am calling it in the constructor I think you given me the clue of my mistake I was declaring combobox before InitializeComponent(); now I tried with giving after that and it's working perfectly thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a semicolon after the USE

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE "+DBName+"; SELECT name FROM sys.Tables", con);
```

Another thought, does the ID/Password in your connection string apply to the other databases as well?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fully working sample using .NET database objects. I didn't pay attention to error handling or anything but just the concept.

```js
SqlConnection insSqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
SqlCommand insSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", insSqlConnection);
SqlDataAdapter insSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(insSqlCommand);
DataTable insDt_Tables = new DataTable();
insSqlConnection.Open();
insSqlDataAdapter.Fill(insDt_Tables);
insSqlConnection.Close();
```

Note that, this query will list tables that are in the defined Initial Catalog in your connection string.

I hope this helps

Comment: To anyone who downvote something... If you are downvoting, can you be kind enough to tell why?

Comment: Use Data Adapter instead of Data reader is another good idea I appreciate  it:)

Comment: Upvoted to nullify because no one commented the reason, But really I dont know whats written up there ;P

Comment: Thanks @Santigo :)

Comment: @Prdp, it just runs the query and populates the values into datatable. Then you can iterate through the datatable and do whatever you want with it